# MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 when run over twice

Tags: java, file, filewriter

Running over a File with this Code works just fine the first time,
but on a second Run (on the same File), `Files.readAllLines` throws said Exception.

All the code does is (for each file but in this case it's just one)
get all the lines from a file, delete it, and then refill it with the same content.

```
for (File file : content) {
    List<String> fillLines = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        fillLines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (fillLines.size() > 0) {
        file.delete();
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, false);

        for (String line : fillLines) {
            fileWriter.write(line);
            if (fillLines.indexOf(line) < fillLines.size() - 1)
                fileWriter.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Might be because of `fileWriter.append(System.lineSeparator());`?

All the other Questioneers were failing the first time because of reading it with a wrong charset. But as I'm able to run it once, I'm not reading but writing something wrong, so changing the charset seems like a workaround that could be avoided.

Stacktrace:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Unknown Source)
```

anything below here points to

```
    fillLines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
```

Comment: `Running over a File with this Code works just fine the first time, but on a second Run, Files.readAllLines throws said Exception` - by second run do you mean second attempt for the same file name, or second file name in the loop. Perhaps there's a problem with the second file.

Comment: Running the program twice over the same File

Comment: The `fillLines.indexOf` is dodgy; have you tried iterating the lines by index? Also, could you post the exception?

Comment: Post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual file with a text editor?

Comment: @daniu tried it real quick with index, no effect.

Comment: @daniu even with "show all characters" so it displays whitespaces and linebreaks -> looks absolutely the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of [Files.readAllLines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-):

> Bytes from the file are decoded into characters using the UTF-8 charset

From the documentation of [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FileWriter.html):

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream.

So, you're writing using the default platform encoding (which, in your case, is not UTF8), and reading with UTF8. That is the cause of the exception. Use the same encoding to write and read. The above documentation explains how to specify the UTF8 encoding to write.

Comment: But can i be sure that this works with every os and every file that can be read like text on every computer around the world?

Comment: No. Reading a file using the wrong encoding will either lead to incorrect characters being read, or to an exception being thrown. But it seems you're the owner of that file (since you're the one deleting and writing it), so you should choose an encoding that supports all the characters/languages you want to support. UTF8 would be a good choice. ISO_8859_1 wouldn't: it only supports 256 characters.

Comment: Yeah thought so, i now defined my own OutputStreamWriter that encodes in UTF-8, which seems to work

Answer (score 0):

```
for (File file : content) {
    Path path = fiel.toPath();
    List<String> fillLines;
    try {
        fillLines = Files.readAllLines(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while reading " + path);
        e.printStackTrace();
        fillLines = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    if (!fillLines.isEmpty()) {
        //Files.delete(path);
        // See -A-
        Files.write(path, fillLines, StandardOpenOptions.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

Why this - even if it is shorter, safer and more consistent?

***The Error***

You do not indicate a Charset for reading and for writing.

Before `Files`, this meant that the platform encoding was used, and an overloaded constructor exists *with* a Charset/String encoding.

And for the very old `FileReader/FileWriter` even that overload does not exist: they always use the platform encoding - `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`.

With `Files` Unicode's **UTF-8** became the default: as java String contains Unicode, the conversion becomes lossless. *Great!*

But after writing with something like Windows-1252, reading with UTF-8 will probably fail, as UTF-8 requires that the 8th bit is used specifically to achieve *valid* multibyte sequences.

**Note: that originally the file was in UTF-8, but once written, no longer is (no valid UTF-8).**

```
// -A-
// Possibly add a BOM (begin of file marker) to identify to Windows
// that this file is in UTF-8 (works for UTF-16 too).
// This is primarily for Notepad. A BOM is redundant, invisible (zero width space)
// and generally inadvisable if not needed.
if (!lines.get(0).startsWith("\uFEFF")) {
    lines.set(0, "\uFEFF" + lines.get(0));
}
```